# Save all PDFs in all tabs in Google Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, pdf, tabs, tabbed-browsing

Tab managers are a dime a dozen in Chrome.

But do any of them let you save the *contents* of all the tabs you have open?

I have forty-odd PDFs of research papers open in my tabs, and I just want to save the PDFs to disk, then close them all -- preferably without right-clicking each and choosing Save As.

Answer (score 0):

This is an awesome request. I found a batch link downloader that can do this.

https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/batch-link-downloader/aiahkbnnpafepcgnhhecilboebmmolnn?utm_source=chrome-app-launcher-info-dialog

Then I created a quick html page that I pasted all my links into and voila.

Comment: Can you explain how this answers the question?   It seems like more work than what the OP wants to do.

Comment: Arggghh I can't get this to work for my site.

Answer (score 0):

Try Tab Save, the only thing i do not like is that it might not be able to have it's own download location to be set, it uses the browser global download folder.

https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/tab-save/lkngoeaeclaebmpkgapchgjdbaekacki